# Any idea as to why my data isn't being passed to the new tableview?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am passing data from one tableview to another. I want the category data that the tableviewA contains to be passed to tableviewB. When I perform the segue, the print data that I have for TableviewB is empty.

This is tableviewA

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let category = listOfCategories[indexPath.row].strCategory
    let vc = MealsByCategoryVC()
    vc.mealCategory = category
    print(category) // Properly returns the category
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchMeals", sender: nil)
    
}
```

This is tableview2

```
class MealsByCategoryVC: UITableViewController {

 var mealCategory : String = ""
 var listOfMeals : [Meals] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Meal category is \(mealCategory)") //This statement returns "Meal category is "
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
let vc = MealsByCategoryVC()
vc.mealCategory = category
performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchMeals", sender: nil)
```

...is not how you pass a value into a view controller that you are creating by calling `performSegue`. The first two lines of that code do nothing at all! The view controller created by the segue is *different* from the one you are creating by saying `MealsByCategoryVC()`; in fact, the latter is just thrown away, uselessly. You are setting the `mealCategory` of the wrong view controller instance.

Instead, implement `prepare(for:sender:)`. That's what it's for. You receive the segue and its destination view controller. *That* is the view controller whose `mealCategory` you need to set.